# Intersections of a circle and segment and intersection of two circles in Euclid's first book

Tags: euclidean-geometry, math-history, geometric-topology

I have thought about the question for some time and now I decide to ask community, I belive some good answers exist.

Consider two facts about Euclidean plane:

1. Suppose $c$ be a circle with radius $OA$ and $B$ be such point of plane, that $OB$ is greater than  $OA$, then there is a point $C$ of intersection.
2. Suppose $c_{1}$, $c_{2}$ be two circles with radii $O_{1}A_{1}$ and $O_{2}A_{2}$, such that sum of $O_{1}A_{1}$ and $O_{2}A_{2}$ is greater than $O_{1}O_{2}$ and difference of $O_{1}A_{1}$ and $O_{2}A_{2}$ is less than $O_{1}O_{2}$, then there exists a point of intersection of $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$.

As I see Euclid in first book does not give any justification of the facts. What would be the reason, a cause of such gap, and what are possibilities to fill the gap? It might be the change of postulates about plane, or additional proposition / propositions in flow of the first book. What is known about that?

Comment: Yes, these do not follow from his axioms / postulates. You need some completeness property. See Hilbet's axioms of geometry for a way to mend that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need completeness.  Historically the first mathematician who fixed this was Pasch; see [Pasch axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasch%27s_axiom) which is far more elementary than completeness and holds in many fields where completeness fails.

You might want to consult Greenberg's book *Euclidean and non-Euclidean geometry* for the background.

Comment: Thanks a lot for an answer, one more question: 
Do the Pasch's axiom together with postulates and axioms of Euclid have sufficient power to infer the facts 1. and 2. from (question) above, or the  foundation extended that way will be still insufficient?

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say that OB is greater than OA?

Comment: As in Euclides firs book, if  I remember correctly : 
"The whole is greater than its part." 
and 
"From given point to draw a straight line equal to a given finite straight line"
e.i. $OB$ is greater than $OA$ means for me that we can draw a segment equal to $OA$ from one of the endpoints of $OB$ in direction of another one so that the obtained is a part of $OB$.

Comment: You should try to study Greenberg's book.  Mathematicians have made quite a bit of progress since Euclid's time.  You should realize that it is not entirely unambiguous to say "equal" in your sentence above.  What do you mean by two intervals being equal?  You are implicitly assuming a notion of congruence of intervals.  Anyway all this is discussed in detail in Greenberg.

Comment: I agree with the comment about the notion of congruence of segments, thanks for reference.