# Where does Euclid use arguments which are true in the "real world" but do not follow from logical consequences?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> I am reading the book "Geometry: Euclid and beyond" and on page 10 there is the following scentence:
>
> For example, Euclid does not hesitate to use arguments from time to time that seem perfetly acceptable in view of our experience of the real world, yet are not logical consequences of his initial assumptions.

Now I wanted to ask if there is such an example in the first 34 propositions in Euclid's Elements. If yes could you maybe tell me which one it is? If no could maybe someone give me an example because I do not see yet what Hartshorne means.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would have to check, but commonly it is things like. "If I have $2$ points on either side of a line then the line through them intersects the line between them." This is intuitively true but I believe it doesn't follow from Euclid's Axioms.

Comment: @Fishbane ah I see, but would it also be possible to check for you?

Comment: This post asks about the case of intersections of circles. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2789605/intersections-of-a-circle-and-segment-and-intersection-of-two-circles-in-euclid

Comment: Just to give an alternative, this page http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI1.html gives some disscusion on the problems with Euclid's first proposition.

Comment: Congruence of triangles is a proposition in Euclid's books and he proves it using "superposition" which is not strictly defined. In Hilbert's geometry congruence principles are axioms.

Comment: @Fishbane perfect thanks a lot, this page helps me a lot!

Comment: @Fishbane I'm sorry to ask here again but I have a question about your webpage. In the critiques about the proof of theorem 1 they wrote that it's not clear that the triangular is plane. But I mean why is this a critical point? I don't get it because I mean it is somehow clear that we need to work in a plane otherwise we can't draw circles with Euclid's  compass, or what do I get wrong?

Comment: @Wave That specific critisism is to do with the fact that in the later chapters of Euclid's Elements he talks about spatial constructions, for that reason technically all of his planar constructions need to prove that they are in fact planar. However if we restrict our attention to planar geometry this concern can be avoided so it isn't a strong objection until spacial constructions start being talked about. Regarding needing a plane to draw a circle, the specific objection still exists even under that assumption.

Comment: @Fishbane ah perfect thanks a lot!

Comment: In essence the problem is that we don't prove that the triangle lies in the plane. Imagine drawing a triangle on a piece of paper which isn't flat, the lines of triangle aren't garuanteed to all be in the same plane even if the points are. Basically the problem is that Euclid doesn't explicitly state when things are in the same plane.

Comment: @Fishbane ah okey so I think the problem was that I immediately assume that we work on a flat paper because otherwise his compass and ruler constructions would not work like this

Comment: @Fishbane but did I get it correct that a plane in the general case do not need to be flat as in $\Bbb{R}^3$ for example? If yes how is then a plane defined?

Comment: @Wave In reality all planes are indeed flat (at least under most definitions I can think of). However in "exotic" geometry you can have planes which aren't flat in the sense that we are used to. The main criticsism is just that it isn't formally proved more than that it is a realistic problem.

Comment: @Fishbane ah I see so it is natural to us that the triangular is plane but we need to prove it formally to be sure

Comment: @Wave Yes that is correct.

Comment: @Fishbane perfect thank you!